Definition of convection heat transfer not unambiguous?
What is actually the definition of convection in the context of heat transfer, if there is one?
Wikipedia states:

Convection (or convective heat transfer) is the transfer of heat from one place to another due to the movement of fluid.
(this or my experimental physics textbook as well).

The other definition strictly defines convection as heat transfer between a solid surface and a fluid, i.e here and many engineering textbooks I could find.

How are the given definitions ambiguous?

The first definition does not involve a solid surface.

Note that it's possible to get convection from a water surface in contact with an air interface, so a solid surface is not a requirement.
